# Fitting Or Warping Text (or an image) Into A Custom Envelope Outline Using HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, three.js, webgl

Let's say that I use some HTML5 markup:

```
<canvas id="e" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("e");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.font = "bold 72px JerseyLetters";
  context.fillText("Bulls", 50, 100);
</script>
```

To make some cool text like this:

[image: Original Text]

Then I decide I want these letters to fit into an envelope that looks like this:

[image: Envelope]

Hoping to get something like this:

[image: Text in envelope]

How would I go about (1) defining an envelope like the one above and then (2) putting the text in the envelope using HTML5 Canvas to get the result?

I am open to either something that directly places text in the envelope or a solution that first creates an image and then fits the image in an envelope.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I added the tags "webgl" and "three.js" to this question on the advice of @markE. I will research those two packages in the mean time as well. I'm very new to .

Comment: In case someone doesn't know, the text will only look like that if you have this font installed on your computer: http://www.dafont.com/jersey-letters.font

Comment: Best I can do is steer you away from a dead-end towards a solution.  You're wanting to transform a line into a curve and your canvas "2d" context does not have that capability.  However, canvas "3d" **does** have that capability. I don't have this magic, but if you add "webgl" and "three.js" tags to you question, you might attract someone who does.

Comment: Thanks @markE, tags added and I'll look into those packages as well.

Answer (score 1):

webGL way:

Do it as a image-processing with pixel-shader.
Render text with 2d canvas, bind webGL texture with buffer and fill texture with canvas image (rendered text). Have prepared envelope that actually maps the area that envelope holds and also every pixel play role of the UV coordinate from the first image. Running that as pixel shader, you have image-to-be-squeezed and envelope (uvs) you'll output final image. That way, it's completely font and text independent. You could even probably make one image-processing step more so you could load any envelope shape and process it on spot, so it becomes font, text and envelope-shape independent.

I'm not sure how well did I explain this.
Hope this helps, though.

Comment: @Tom D, you can also create polygon that has envelope shape and assign texture that will be fitted on it that you draw in canvas previously. It's fully dynamic.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I'm interested on this approach but I'm a beginner with WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

SVG provides these sort of text transforms. See http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/TEXT_PATH/TextPath.html

EDIT: This link appears to be converting the text to actual SVG. Probably not going to be helpful for you, sorry.

Comment: Actually the Live Text Effects seem promising. It's very important to me to maintain the original text so I can easily change it. I'll look into this more. Thanks!